# I get the error code 500 and Request failed with status code 401 in my react project

Tags: reactjs, node.js, authentication, jwt, token

I followed this YT Video (https://youtu.be/0aPLk2e2Z3g?si=tgdoWLkbLn8vOJ5r), when I try to upload a post I get following error message:

> Write.jsx:24 AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code
> 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…},
> request: XMLHttpRequest, …}code: "ERR_BAD_RESPONSE"config:
> {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1),
> transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}message: "Request failed
> with status code 500"name: "AxiosError"request: XMLHttpRequest
> {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials:
> false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}response: {data: '\n\n\n<meta
> char…636strawberry_jam.jpg'\n\n\n', status:
> 500, statusText: 'Internal Server Error', headers: AxiosHeaders,
> config: {…}, …}stack: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code
> 500\n    at settle
> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:75552:12)\n    at
> XMLHttpRequest.onloadend
> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:74214:66)\n    at
> Axios.request (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:74715:41)\n
> at async upload (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2120:19)\n
> at async handleClick
> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2128:20)"[[Prototype]]:
> Error Write.jsx:47
>
> ```
>     POST http://localhost:3000/posts/ 401 (Unauthorized) dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:258 xhr @ xhr.js:49 dispatchRequest @
> ```
>
> dispatchRequest.js:51
> _request @ Axios.js:170 request @ Axios.js:40 httpMethod @ Axios.js:209 wrap @ bind.js:5 handleClick @ Write.jsx:47 await in
> handleClick (asynchron) callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
> invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
> invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
> invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @
> react-dom.development.js:4291 executeDispatch @
> react-dom.development.js:9041 processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @
> react-dom.development.js:9073 processDispatchQueue @
> react-dom.development.js:9086 dispatchEventsForPlugins @
> react-dom.development.js:9097 (anonym) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
> batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140 batchedUpdates @
> react-dom.development.js:3991 dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @
> react-dom.development.js:9287
> dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay
> @ react-dom.development.js:6465 dispatchEvent @
> react-dom.development.js:6457 dispatchDiscreteEvent @
> react-dom.development.js:6430 22 weitere Frames anzeigen Weniger
> anzeigen Write.jsx:57 AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status
> code 401', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…},
> request: XMLHttpRequest, …}code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"config:
> {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1),
> transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}message: "Request failed
> with status code 401"name: "AxiosError"request: XMLHttpRequest
> {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials:
> false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}response: {data: 'Not
> authenticated!', status: 401, statusText: 'Unauthorized', headers:
> AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}stack: "AxiosError: Request failed with
> status code 401\n    at settle
> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:75552:12)\n    at
> XMLHttpRequest.onloadend
> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:74214:66)\n    at
> Axios.request (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:74715:41)\n
> at async handleClick
> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2142:12)"[[Prototype]]:
> Error

I'm not sure what the issue is with the token. I uploaded my code on GitHub (https://github.com/Kakegurui-Mary/blog-node.js-react-project), to make it easier to review my files.

Additionally I would like to add rating (from 0 to 5 such as 0.5, 1.0, 2.5, etc.) and comment feature to the recipes, in which files should I incoperate those features into and what changes are required? I appreciate any help, thank you!